# Как перенаправить команду print в cmd?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я написал простенькую програму с интерфейсом PyQt5.Которая выводит данный вписанные пользователем в LineEdit в консоль PyCharm, а так же добавляется строка "Shutdown /s /t ".

На выходе получается это: "Shutdown /s /t + (данные введённые пользователем)"
например: "Shutdown /s /t 400"
Но это всё выводится в консоль PyCharm.А мне надо,чтобы это выводилось в cmd и выполнялось,выключая компьютер через заданное время.Как мне можно этого добиться?

Мне уже объясняли как можно сделать подобное с помощью os.system и QTimer.Но я не могу додуматься как мне это связать.

```
validador = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9]*")
ok = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(validador)
self.lineEdit.setValidator(ok)
self.lineEdit.setFocus()

# При нажатии на кнопку получение значения из line edit

self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print_lineEdit)

def print_lineEdit(self):
    text = self.lineEdit.text()  # значение из поля LineEdit
    print(f"Shutdown /s /t  {text}")
```

Comment: Сделай `import subprocess` сверху, потом делай вместо print - `subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-s", "-t", text])`

Comment: Господи,спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Sasha Gulyaev узнаю знакомые строки, а что у нас с предыдущим вопросом?

Comment: Рад, что помог. Саша, Пж тогда тыкни там ниже на треугольник вверх и на галочку.

Comment: S. Nick,С предыдущим вопросом всё отлично.Спасибо и вам за помощь.Сейчас отмечу ваш ответ в том вопросе)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть правленая копипаста [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764126/how-to-make-a-python-script-which-can-logoff-shutdown-and-restart-a-computer/39977903):

```
def shutdown(time):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-s", "-t", time])
```

И там где нужно ты вызываешь `shutdown(time)` где time это переменная с временем.